# How to render a light source through transparent object?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, lighting

I am trying to render this antique pool table scene, and I am close to a realistic look, but noticed that the light source should be showing through the glass of the lamp (crudely illustrated in image). Does anybody know how to make this show in the render? I have two point lights @ 25 W and two bulb-shaped objects with emission set to 5. Have tried a few different things but nothing has worked yet. Thank you in advance[image]

Comment: Hello so why are you not glad with the emission objects?

Comment: I played with the emission more. It was 10x too weak, now I am glad! Thank you